# Replace characters in a delimited part of a file

Tags: unix, sed, replace, character

I have the file `teste.txt` with the following content:

```
02183101399205000 GBTD9VBYMBQ 04455927964
02183101409310000 XBQMPL1C93B 27699484827
54183101003651000 1WFG3SNVDG9 71530894204
```

I execute the command

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{18\}\)[0-9]/\1#/g' teste.txt
```

The result is:

```
02183101399205000 GBTD9VBYMBQ 04455927964
02183101409310000 XBQMPL1C93B 27699484827
54183101003651000 #WFG3SNVDG9 71530894204
```

Only the 19th position in line 3 is changed from `1` to `#`.

I would like to know how can I change all numeric characters from the 19th to the 30th position.

The expected result is:

```
02183101399205000 GBTD#VBYMBQ 04455927964
02183101409310000 XBQMPL#C##B 27699484827
54183101003651000 #WFG#SNVDG# 71530894204
```

Comment: Sed is doing exactly what your pattern asked for - looking for 18 characters at the beginning of a line immediately followed by one numeric character.  Awk would be a better tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

An awk command to accomplish your goal:

```
awk '{ gsub(/[0-9]/,"#",$2); print }' teste.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/./&\n/30;s//\n&/19;h;s/[0-9]/#/g;H;x;s/\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/' file
```

Surround the string, which is from the 19th to the 30th character, by newlines and make a copy. Replace all digits by `#`'s. Append this string to the original and use pattern matching to rearrange the strings to make a new string with the unchanged parts either side of the changed part, at the same time discarding the introduced newlines.

An alternative method, utilising the fact the the fields are space separated:

```
sed -r ':a;s/( \S*)[0-9](\S* )/\1#\2/;ta' file
```

In fact the two methods can be combined:

```
sed -r 's/./&\n/30;s//\n&/19;:a;s/(\n.*)[0-9](.*\n)/\1#\2/;ta;s/\n//g' file
```